# Stratified sites/topoi and constructible sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, constructible-sheaves, l-adic-sheaves

Is it possible to define (possibly derived) categories of constructible sheaves over sites more general than those of open subsets of topological spaces while still retaining essential features, like how if $\Lambda$ is a Noetherian ring then constructible sheaves of $\Lambda$-modules will span a thick subcategory of the abelian category of sheaves of $\Lambda$-modules ? Will such a generalisation of constructible sheaves involve defining stratifications of sites/sheaf topoi, and if so, how would we go about defining such notions of stratifications ?

In particular, I am interested in "direct" definitions of constructible étale, lisse-étale, and fppf sheaves over a given scheme/algebraic space/Artin stack $X$. Certain restrictions that I am willing to work under are that $X$ is (locally) of finite type over some base scheme $S$ that is affine, regular, Noetherian, of dimension $\leq 1$, and of characteristic $p \geq 0$, and that the ring of coefficient $\Lambda$ is a Gorenstein local ring of dimension $0$ and characteristic $\ell \not = p$.

Comment: Am I mistaken? Constructible sheaves are never defined over sites of "open subsets of topological spaces" for schemes of characteristic $p$, but rather on its étale site? Anyway, if you are looking for a modern reference, maybe you could consult [The pro-étale topology for schemes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.1198.pdf) and [Constructible sheaves on schemes and a categorical Künneth formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.02853.pdf).

Comment: @Z.M Thank you for the references. In response to your question: I might very well be wrong, but aren't constructible sheaves on a given scheme defined with respect to a stratification of that scheme into Zariski-locally closed subschemes (which would make constructibility not a "purely étale" notion) ?

Comment: It does not seem possible to say something "purely étale": an étale morphism is an open immersion [if and only if](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025G) it is a monomorphism.